# Extraer y guardar datos de varias tablas relacionadas en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy desarrollando una ficha de inscripción en *Laravel 5.4*, pues he creado cinco tablas que tienen una relación de uno a muchos:

La tabla principal `tblFicha` tiene una relación de uno a mucho con las tablas: `tblDiocesis`, `tblRegionales`-> esta tabla es padre de ' tblDistrito' y finalmente 'tblFuncion' tiene valores automáticos, excepto la tabla `Fichas`, que es donde el usuario va a crear sus inscripciones. Desde *Laravel*.

He hecho todas las relaciones correctamente, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo desarrollo el código en el *Store* para guardar los valores?

**Formulario:**

[image: Formulario para crear insertar nuevas inscripciones en la table_Ficha]

El código del formulario:

```
<div class="form-group">{!!Form::text(
    'nombre', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Escribe tu  nombre']
)!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">{!!Form::text(
    'apellido', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Escribe tu apellido']
)!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">{!!Form::text(
    'email', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Escribe tu  email']
)!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">{!!Form::text(
    'cedula', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Escribe tu cedula']
)!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">{!!Form::text(
'telefono', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Escribe tu telefono']
)!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">{!!Form::text( 'congregaciones', null,
    ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Si perteneces a una congregaciones']
)!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Diocesis -->
    {!! Form::select('diocesi_id',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona tu diocesis'])!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Regionales-->
    {!! Form::select(
        'regional_id',['placeholder' =>'Selecciona tu Regional Educativo']
    )!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Distritos-->
    {!! Form::select('distritos',['placeholder' => 'Si seleccionas tu distrito']
    )!!}</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Funciones-->
    {!! Form::select('funcion_id', ['placeholder' => 'Selecciona tu funcion'])!!}</div>
<div class="form-group ">{!!Form::submit(
    'Guardar nueva inscripcion', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']
)!!}<a href="ficha" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a></div>
```

Las relaciones de `tblFicha` con las otras:

```
class Ficha extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'apellido','cedula','email','telefono','diocesi_id',
        'congregaciones', 'regional_id', 'funcion_id'
    ];
    public function regionales(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Regional');}
    public function cargos(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Cargo');}
    public function diocesis(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Diocesi');}
}
```

El controlador (es donde se me complica):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $ficha = new Ficha;

    $ficha->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $ficha->apellido = $request->apellido;
    $ficha->cedula = $request->cedula;
    $ficha->email = $request->email;
    $ficha->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $ficha->diocesi_id = $request->diocesi_id;
    $ficha->congregaciones = $request->congregaciones;
    $ficha->regional_id = $request->regional_id;
    $ficha->funcion_id = $request->funcion_id;

    $ficha->save();

    return redirect('ficha')->with('msg', 'Se inscribio correctamente, gracias, te esperamos.');
}
```

Comment: como sacos datos de varias tablas relacionada en laravel y luego guardar la información?

Comment: El modelo `Funcion` con qué otro modelo está relacionado? con `Ficha`?

Comment: Si->el modelo Ficha tiene una relación de uno a mucho con el ->modelo Funcion... como los otros modelos: Regional, Diocesi... gracias brother de antemano por tu ayuda...

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes instanciar a cada modelo e ir agregandolos

```
$ficha = new Ficha;

$ficha->nombre = $request->nombre;
$ficha->apellido = $request->apellido;
...
...
$regional = new Regional();
$regional->name = 'xxx'
$ficha->regionales($regional);
...
$ficha->save();
```

Ó tambien agregandolos directamente

```
$ficha->regionales(['name'=>'xxx']);
$ficha->save();
```